# Hacker News API, KeyError: 'title

Tags: python, web

Just starting to learn python, and I am starting to learn the web-based side of it.

Following the instructions I have, i keep getting a KeyError: 'title' on line 18. Now I see it as the request not returning a title so it gives an error, how would I write it up to give a generic description if there is no 'title'???

```
import requests

from operator import itemgetter as ig

url = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json'
r = requests.get(url)
print("Status Code:", r.status_code)

submission_ids= r.json()
submission_dicts = []
for submission_id in submission_ids[:30]:
    url= ("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item" + str(submission_id) + '.json')
    submission_r = requests.get(url)
    print(submission_r.status_code)
    response_dict = submission_r.json()

    submission_dict = {
    'title': response_dict['title'],
    'link': "https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=" +str(submission_id),
    'comments': response_dict.get('descendants', 0)
}

submission_dicts = sorted(submission_dicts, key= ig('comments'), reverse= True)

for submission_dict in submission_dicts:
    print("\nTitle:", submission_dict['title'])
    print("Discussion link:", submission_dict['link'])
    print("Comments:", submission_dict['comments'])
```

> Status Code: 200
>      401
>      Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\Shit Head\Documents\Programming\Tutorial Files\hn_submissions.py", line 18, in <module>
>           'title': response_dict['title'], 
>       KeyError: 'title'
>       [Finished in 1.2s]

Comment: May we see the line 18 and all other relevant lines, as well as the full error message?

Comment: Yeah sorry, first post, was trying to figure out how to get the code in there.

Comment: So, your `response_dict` does not have a "title" key. You should check `if "title" in response_dict` before using the item.

Answer (score 0):

> Following the instructions I have, i keep getting a KeyError: 'title' on line 18. Now I see it as the request not returning a title so it gives an error, how would I write it up to give a generic description if there is no 'title'???

It sounds like you're just looking for the [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method:

> `get(key[, default])`
>
> > Return the value for *key* if *key* is in the dictionary, else *default*. If *default* is not given, it defaults to `None`, so that this method never raises a `KeyError`.

So, instead of this:

```
'title': response_dict['title'],
```

… you do this:

```
'title': response_dict.get('title', 'Generic Hacker News Submission'),
```

---

Under the covers, this is just a more convenient way to write something you could have done anyway. The following are all pretty much equivalent:

```
title = response_dict.get('title', 'Generic')

title = response_dict['title'] if title in response_dict else 'Generic'

if title in response_dict:
    title = response_dict['title']
else:
    title = 'Generic'

try:
    title = response_dict['title']
except KeyError:
    title = 'Generic'
```

This is worth knowing because Python only usually provides shortcuts like `get` for really common cases like looking things up in a dictionary. If you wanted to do the same thing with, say, a list that may be empty or have one item, or a file that might or might not exist, or a regular expression that might return a match with a group string or might return None, you'd need to do things the long way.

Comment: +1 thats exactly what I was trying to figure out, I was unaware of being able to do the `get` call and then add a default setting if it returned nothing.